# Visual Studio 2010 tool to order members inside #region

Tags: visual-studio-2010

There exist a tool for Visual studio which order alphabetically the members grouped by #region ?

means

```
#region 
A1() ...
A2() ...
A0() ...
B1() ...
Z1() ...
B5() ...
#endregion

#region 
C1() ...
C2() ...
C0() ...
D1() ...
X1() ...
Y5() ...
#endregion
```

With that tool, I want like:

```
#region 
A0() ...
A1() ...
A2() ...
B1() ...
B5() ...
Z1() ...
#endregion

#region 
C0() ...
C1() ...
C2() ...
D1() ...
X1() ...
Y5() ...
#endregion
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Resharper has a feature called [Type Members Layout](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Languages__CSharp__Type_Members_Layout.html) that does this.  Documentation is [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Usage_Scenarios__Reordering_Type_Members.html).